# T-SQL - Merge all columns from source to target table w/o listing all the columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-merge

I'm trying to merge a very wide table from a source (linked Oracle server) to a target table (SQL Server 2012) w/o listing all the columns. Both tables are identical except for the records in them.
This is what I have been using:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE TargetTable
INSERT INTO TargetTable
SELECT *
FROM SourceTable
```

When/if I get this working I would like to make it a procedure so that I can pass into it the source, target and match key(s) needed to make the update. For now I would just love to get it to work at all.

```
USE ThisDatabase  
GO

DECLARE
  @Columns VARCHAR(4000) = (
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME + ',' 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TargetTable' 
    FOR XML PATH('')
    )

MERGE TargetTable AS T

USING (SELECT * FROM SourceTable) AS S
ON (T.ID = S.ID AND T.ROWVERSION = S.ROWVERSION)

WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET @Columns = S.@Columns

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
  INSERT (@Columns)
  VALUES (S.@Columns)
```

Please excuse my noob-ness. I feel like I'm only half way there, but I don't understand some parts of SQL well enough to put it all together. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously mentioned in the answers, if you don't want to specify the columns , then you have to write a dynamic query. 
Something like this in your case should help:

```
DECLARE
@Columns VARCHAR(4000) = (
SELECT COLUMN_NAME + ',' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TargetTable' 
FOR XML PATH('')
)

DECLARE  @MergeQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE  @UpdateQuery VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE  @InsertQuery VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE  @InsertQueryValues VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE  @Col VARCHAR(200)

SET @UpdateQuery='Update Set '
SET @InsertQuery='Insert ('
SET @InsertQueryValues=' Values('


WHILE LEN(@Columns) > 0
BEGIN
   SET @Col=left(@Columns, charindex(',', @Columns+',')-1);

   IF @Col<> 'ID' AND @Col <> 'ROWVERSION'
   BEGIN
      SET @UpdateQuery= @UpdateQuery+ 'TargetTable.'+ @Col + ' = SourceTable.'+ @Col+ ','
      SET @InsertQuery= @InsertQuery+@Col + ','
     SET @InsertQueryValues=@InsertQueryValues+'SourceTable.'+ @Col+ ','
   END

  SET @Columns = stuff(@Columns, 1, charindex(',', @Columns+','), '')
END

SET @UpdateQuery=LEFT(@UpdateQuery, LEN(@UpdateQuery) - 1)
SET @InsertQuery=LEFT(@InsertQuery, LEN(@InsertQuery) - 1)
SET @InsertQueryValues=LEFT(@InsertQueryValues, LEN(@InsertQueryValues) - 1)

SET @InsertQuery=@InsertQuery+ ')'+  @InsertQueryValues +')'

SET @MergeQuery=
N'MERGE TargetTable
USING SourceTable
ON TargetTable.ID = SourceTable.ID AND TargetTable.ROWVERSION =    SourceTable.ROWVERSION ' +

'WHEN MATCHED THEN ' + @UpdateQuery +
' WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN '+@InsertQuery +';'

Execute sp_executesql @MergeQuery
```

> If you want more information about Merge, you could read the this excellent [article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/)

Comment: You can do this without loops. You can select all you want with help of `for xml path`

Answer (score 0):

Don't feel bad. It takes time. Merge has interesting syntax. I've actually never used it. I read Microsoft's documentation on it, which is very helpful and even has examples. I think I covered everything. I think there may be a slight amount of tweaking you might have to do, but I think it should work.

Here's the documentation for MERGE:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

As for your code, I commented pretty much everything to explain it and show you how to do it.

### This part is to help write your merge statement

```
USE ThisDatabase    --This says what datbase context to use.
                    --Pretty much what database your querying.
                    --Like this: database.schema.objectName
GO

DECLARE
  @SetColumns VARCHAR(4000) = (
    SELECT CONCAT(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME),' = S.',QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME),',',CHAR(10))   --Concat just says concatenate these values. It's adds the strings together.
                                                                                        --QUOTENAME adds brackets around the column names
                                                                                        --CHAR(10) is a line break for formatting purposes(totally optional)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    --WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TargetTable' 
    FOR XML PATH('')
    )   --This uses some fancy XML trick to get your Columns concatenated into one row. 
        --What really is in your table is a column of your column names in different rows.
        --BTW If the columns names in both tables are identical, then this will work.
DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(4000) = (
    SELECT QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ','


    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    --WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TargetTable' 
    FOR XML PATH('')
    )

SET @Columns = SUBSTRING(@Columns,0,LEN(@Columns)) -- this gets rid off the comma at the end of your list
SET @SetColumns = SUBSTRING(@SetColumns,0,LEN(@SetColumns)) --same thing here

SELECT @SetColumns --Your going to want to copy and paste this into your WHEN MATCHED statement
SELECT @Columns --Your going to want to copy this into your WHEN NOT MATCHED statement
GO
```

### Merge Statement

Especially look at my notes on ROWVERSION.

```
MERGE INTO TargetTable AS T

USING SourceTable AS S --Don't really need to write SELECT * FROM since you need the whole table anyway
ON (T.ID = S.ID AND T.[ROWVERSION] = S.[ROWVERSION])    --These are your matching parameters
                                                        --One note on this, if ROWVERSION is different versions of the same data you don't want to have RowVersion here
                                                        --Like lets say you have ID 1 ROWVERSION 2 in your source but only version 1 in your targetTable
                                                        --If you leave T.ID =S.ID AND T.ROWVERSION = S.ROWVERSION, then it will insert the new ROWVERSION
                                                        --So you'll have two versions of ID 1

WHEN MATCHED THEN                   --When TargetTable ID and ROWVERSION match in the matching parameters
                                    --Update the values in the TargetTable
    UPDATE SET /*Copy and Paste @SetColumnss here*/
                --Should look like this(minus the "--"):
                --Col1 = S.Col1,
                --Col2 = S.Col2,
                --Col3 = S.Col3,
                --Etc...

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   --This says okay there are no rows with the existing ID, now insert a new row
  INSERT (col1,col2,col3) --Copy and paste @Columns in between the parentheses. Should look like I show it. Note: This is insert into target table so your listing the target table columns
  VALUES (col1,col2,col3)       --Same thing here. This is the list of source table columns
```